# Singular values of a Gaussian random times deterministic diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices, gaussian, singular-values

Suppose $S$ is a tall-and-skinny $m \times n$ matrix with *iid* Gaussian entries and $D$ is a $m \times m$ deterministic diagonal matrix. What can be said about the bounds on the largest and smallest singular values of a product $DS$? [This post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258993/product-of-gaussian-random-matrix-and-a-deterministic-diagonal-matrix) mentions a relevant "classical result", but I can't find a proof of that statement.

Answer (score 1):

See [The smallest singular value of deformed random rectangular matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.04050).

If the diagonal elements of $D$ are of order unity then the smallest singular value of $DS$ is of order $\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}$ with high probability. The largest singular value is of order $\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}$.

If there is no constraint on $D$ the upper bound is the product of the largest singular value of $D$ and the largest singular value of $S$ (the latter being of order $\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}$).

Comment: What about a case when there is no constrain on the values of elements of **_D_** except that they are placed in a decreasing order?

Comment: since the distribution of $D$ is unitarily invariant, the order of the elements of $D$ is irrelevant; the cited paper considers the more general case that the diagonal elements of $D$ lie in an interval $(c,1/c)$ for some $c\in(0,1)$.